# Convective derivative vs total derivative

Tags: fluid-dynamics, time, notation, differentiation, flow

I was wondering what is the difference between the convective/material derivative and the total derivative. We were introduced to the notion of material derivative

$$ \frac{D\vec{u}}{Dt}=\frac{\partial \vec{u}}{\partial t}+(\vec u\cdot\vec{\nabla})\vec u $$

in fluid mechanics, but I cannot see how this is any different to the time derivative of a vector field $\vec{u}({\vec{x(t)}},t)$ and just applying the chain rule?

If there is no difference, why introduce new notation of $ \frac{ D\vec{u}}{D t} $ instead of just using the standard notation $\frac{d\vec{u}}{dt} $?

Comment: Different authors use different notation.

Comment: Shouldn't the equation for the convective derivative be $\frac{Du}{Dt}=\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial t}+\vec v\cdot\vec{\nabla} u$ where $\vec v$ is the velocity of the flow and ${u}=u(x,t)$ is the material? And I believe $D/Dt$ implies it's a covariant derivative.

Comment: when the v of the frame of reference is the same as the velocity of the fluid then they are both the same. The material derivative is just a special case with a special v

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have to be careful when calling the material derivative a total time derivative calculated by applying the chain rule, because it is not just that.

For starters, you need to distinguish between the [Lagrangian and Eulerian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) formalisms in continuum mechanics. The Eulerian formalism is expressed in terms of spacial coordinates $(x,y,z)$ and time. Spatial coordinates here are **independent variables** that describe fixed positions in space, and they're not a function of time. On the contrary, the Lagrangian formalism is based on following a certain specific fluid element in the flow, whose position is given as $\mathbf X(\mathbf x_0,t)$, where $\mathbf x_0=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is the initial position of the fluid element.

Consider a certain flow quantity $q$ expressed in the Lagrangian formalism: $$q=q(\mathbf X(\mathbf x_0,t),t).$$ 
The total time derivative of $q$, calculated by applying the chain rule is:
$$\frac{dq}{dt}=\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathbf X=cst}+(\mathbf u\cdot\nabla_\mathbf X)q.$$
Note that the partial derivative with respect to time is calculated at constant $\mathbf X$, and the gradient in the second term at the right hand side is calculated with respect to $\mathbf X$, whereas the material derivative is actually expressed in the Eulerian formalism:
$$\frac{Dq}{Dt}=\left(\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}\right)_{\mathbf x=cst}+(\mathbf u\cdot\nabla_\mathbf x)q.$$
where $\mathbf x=(x,y,z)$ is the independent position vector.

So how do we pass from the total time derivative to the material derivative? Well lucky we are; the mapping between $\mathbf X$ and $\mathbf x$ is a very simple one:
$$X(\mathbf x_0,t)=x$$
$$Y(\mathbf x_0,t)=y$$
$$Z(\mathbf x_0,t)=z$$
which means that the partial time derivative of $q$ at constant $\mathbf X$ is the same as the partial time derivative at constant $\mathbf x$, and the gradient with respect to $\mathbf X$ is the same as the gradient with respect to $\mathbf x$. Thus, the two expressions become equivalent.

Comment: Great answer. Would it be correct to simply say the relationship is X=x?

Comment: @electronpusher Indeed it would.

Comment: You said that $x,y,z$ are spatial coordinates independent of time but when mapping between Eulerian and Lagrangian coordinates, doesn't it make spatial coordinates the functions of time $x=X(\mathbf x_0,t)$, $y=Y(\mathbf x_0,t)$, $z=Z(\mathbf x_0,t)$?

Comment: @user366089 The equality should not be read as an identity. $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ are functions of time, and the values of these functions at any point are equal to the spatial coordinates of that point $(x, y, z)$. The spatial coordinates, however, are independent variables and not functions of time.

Comment: I don't get how this equality is understood. Even though spatial coordinates are independent of time, they still vary with time?

Comment: @user366089 No. $x$ is a spatial coordinate which is defined for any point in space and has a fixed value at each point which doesn't change with time. $X$ is the position of a fluid element moving in space, thus it is a function of time. However, at any point in space, the value of $X$ is equal to that of $x$ at the same point.

Comment: Thanks. Lastly, how do you define $\mathbf{u}$? Is that right $\mathbf{u}=(\frac{dx}{dt},\frac{dy}{dt},\frac{dz}{dt})$? Or maybe $\mathbf{u}=(\frac{dX}{dt},\frac{dY}{dt},\frac{dZ}{dt})$?

Comment: @user366089 $\mathbf u$ is defined by the latter formula $\left(dX/dt, dY/dt, dZ/dt\right)$, as given by the chain rule.

Comment: And that's for both Eulerian and Lagrangian specification, no?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the definitions below

Total derivative:
$$\frac{d}{dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \frac{dx_i}{dt}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

Material derivative:
$$\frac{D}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + u_i\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}$$

Would you agree they are the same if $u_i=\frac{dx_i}{dt}$?

Why people use inconsistent notation for both? I do not know.

In my opinion the total derivative is used most often in mathematics whereas the material derivative is used most often in physics. In physics, $\frac{dx_i}{dt}$ has a clear physical interpretation as the instantaneous velocity. In mathematics, there is not necessarily a physical interpretation and the variable notation may be arbitrary.

The next question is, do you understand what the physical interpretation of the material derivative is?